# How to add a role to multiple users with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this command to give a role to a user ,

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def role(self,ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.name}, {role.name} Role have been given to {user.mention}")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
```

what I is a command like role @role @user1 @user2 @user3.... to give a role to multiple users with a single command.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def role(self, ctx, role: discord.Role, *users: discord.Member):
    for user in users:
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

`{prefix}role @role @user1 @user2`